# Child SVGSVGElement disappears during transform transition (Safari/Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, safari, transition

Child disappearing during changes to container transform (with transition) in Safari/Chrome. 
Issue occurs more when child is an SVGSVGElement, scale is > ~3 and with rapid changes to transform.

Setting `transform3d` or `backface-visibility:hidden` on child has no effect. `willChange:transform` on transformed element has no effect.

Doesn't happen in Firefox — the transition may freeze and then jump to the end.

Can induce issue most consistently in following standalone example by repeatedly pressing 1,2,3 in rapid succession.

Occurs in Safari and Chrome on mac, and in mobile safari under similar conditions.

Is this a known issue/limitation? 
Is there information about hard limits on CSS transitions? 
Am I doing something in the example that's incorrect?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">        
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <title>Zoom test</title>
    <style>

         html, body {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
        }     
        #wrapper{
            transition:all 1s;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body touch-action="none">
    <div id="wrapper">          
        <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 612 792"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fbd3d4;}.cls-2{fill:none;stroke:#231f20;stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style></defs><title>lines</title><rect class="cls-1" width="612" height="792"/><polyline class="cls-2" points="28.35 5.25 585.49 5.25 28.35 68.51 585.49 84.84 28.35 135.86"/><polyline class="cls-2" points="28.35 135.86 585.49 135.86 28.35 199.12 585.49 215.45 28.35 266.47"/><polyline class="cls-2" points="28.35 266.47 585.49 266.47 28.35 329.73 585.49 346.06 28.35 397.08"/><polyline class="cls-2" points="28.35 397.08 585.49 397.08 28.35 460.35 585.49 476.67 28.35 527.69"/><polyline class="cls-2" points="28.35 527.69 585.49 527.69 28.35 590.96 585.49 607.28 28.35 658.31"/><polyline class="cls-2" points="28.35 658.31 585.49 658.31 28.35 721.57 585.49 737.9 28.35 788.92"/></svg>        
    </div>
    <script>        
        var w = document.querySelector("#wrapper");        
        document.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
            w.style.transformOrigin = "0 0";
            if(e.key == "1"){
                w.style.transform = "translate(0px,0px) scale(1)"
            }else if(e.key == "2"){
                w.style.transform = "translate(200px,200px) scale(4)"                                    
            }else if(e.key == "3"){
                w.style.transform = "translate(-1200px,-4000px) scale(7)"
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: You should report browser bugs to the browser's bugtracking sites.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Krosh, Apologies; Clarified specific question in post.

Comment: @RobertLongson. Wasn't sure if this was a bug given similar behavior in Safari/Chrome but I've gone on to report it just in case.